# Referencing user-defined configuration variable in Grails?

Tags: grails, configuration

I'm trying to add a section of configuration to my Config.groovy file, and reference the entries elsewhere.

This will be used for networking from different locations, and it needs route to the correct place based on who is using it.

The basic layout in the config would look something like this:

```
externalApp {
    host: "xxx.xxx.xx.xx"
    port: "xxxx"
}
```

I need to place the "host" and "port" in separate sections of the application, inside URL strings like so:

```
http://**externalApp.host**:**externalApp.port**
```

...etc. But I can't seem to find a simple way to reference the actual configuration in the file. Is there an easy way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to reference host and port in other places in the Config.groovy, or you want to reference them in your application code?

Comment: Take a look to [this][1], works for me!!!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18528665/2835520

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to get a reference to these config parameters in your application then you can use:

```
def host = ConfigurationHolder.config.externalApp.host
def port = ConfigurationHolder.config.externalApp.port

def url = "http://${host}:${port}"
```

`ConfigurationHolder` is deprecated in Grails 1.3.7, you're supposed to use `GrailsApplication` instead. You can get a reference to an instance of this class via dependency inject, e.g.

```
class MyController {

  def grailsApplication
}
```

Then get a reference to your configuration using:

```
ConfigObject config = grailsApplication.config
```

Comment: Hmm. I'm getting an error that says "config" is null. The file name is just Config.groovy. Any idea why this isn't working? My code looks exactly like the second example, substituting real values.

Comment: The first example works, actually, so this answer was fine. Thank you so much!