# How to refer to one configuration variable from other configuration variable inside Config.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, config

For example:

Config.groovy:

```
// ...
grails.variable1 = "a"
grails.varibale2 = "${grails.variable1}bc"
//...
```

**UPDATE 1**

Way shown above works with grails 2.2.3. For older versions of grails please use solution @tim_yates suggested

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to declare a variable:

```
def rootVar = 'a'
grails.variable1 = rootVar
grails.varibale2 = "${rootVar}bc"
```

Or you might be able to do it via a closure (not tested):

```
grails.variable1 = 'a'
grails.varibale2 = { -> "${grails.variable1}bc" }()
```

Comment: this is not going to work. I need to access config context somehow. I need to refer to many config variables from many other config variables

Comment: You can't access the config from inside the config unless it's done via a Closure...  Updated my answer...

Comment: @archer Actually, your way *seems* work with Grails 2.3.0.RC2...  I need to run some tests

Comment: Thank you. I'll check with 2.3.0.RC2 myself

Comment: ;) nice to hear that.