# Reusing Grails variables inside Config.groovy

Tags: grails, groovy, configuration

In my `Config.groovy` I have:

```
// Lots of other stuff up here...

environments {
    development {
        myapp.port = 7500
    }
    production {
        myapp.port = 7600
    }
}

fizz {
    buzz {
        foo = "Port #${myapp.port}"
    }
}
```

When I run my app via `grails -Dgrails.env=development run-app`, my web app spins up without errors, but then at runtime I see that the value of `fizz.buzz.foo` is "*Port #[:]*". **I would expect it to be "Port #7500".**

Why isn't Grails seeing my var?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to refer to one configuration variable from other configuration variable inside Config.groovy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18528595/how-to-refer-to-one-configuration-variable-from-other-configuration-variable-ins)

Comment: Another [possible duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20754029/2051952).

Comment: @dmahapatro that's a slightly different case, as there they are trying to access config values from inside the `log4j` closure, which is evaluated later than the rest of the configuration.

Comment: @IanRoberts true. Late binding is what it would need.

Comment: @dmahapatro or in the log4j case simply prefix with `config.` as the complete parsed and merged configuration is available within the log4j DSL as `config`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way is to simply use variables within your config file like this:

```
def appPort = 7500

environments {
    production {
        appPort = 7600
        myapp.port = appPort
    }
}

fizz {
    buzz {
        foo = "Port #$appPort"
    }
}
```

And also, you don't need to send the *-Dgrails.environment=development* when you execute the run-app, it's the default one.

Comment: This will work for values specified directly in `Config.groovy` but it won't allow you to override `myapp.port` in a `grails.config.locations` external configuration file (or rather, you can override `myapp.port` but `fizz.buzz.foo` will still take the value from `Config.groovy` rather than the overridden one).

Answer (score 3):

You could probably get away with this if `myapp.port` were not in an `environments` block but that's a side effect of the way `Config.groovy` is processed rather than being intentional.  And if you were to override `myapp.port` in an external config file then `fizz.buzz.foo` would still end up with the value from `Config.groovy`, not the override from the external.

You could make it a late-binding GString using a closure to pull the value from `grails.util.Holders.config` when `fizz.buzz.foo` is *referenced* rather than when it is *defined*:

```
foo = "Port #${-> Holders.config.myapp.port}"
```

This is different from `"Port #${Holders.config.myapp.port}"` which would attempt to access the config at the point where `Config.groovy` is being parsed.

If the value you're defining here is one that will ultimately end up defining a property of a Spring bean (for example many of the spring-security-core plugin configuration options become bean properties) then you may be able to do

```
foo = 'Port #${myapp.port}'
```

with *single* rather than double quotes.  This causes the resulting config entry to contain the literal string `${myapp.port}`, which will be resolved against the config by the Spring property placeholder mechanism when it is used as a bean property value.