# How in Grails override config variable in external config file so that variables dependant on that variable are updated too?

Tags: grails, groovy, config, lazy-evaluation

I have an external and internal config in my grails application:

**Config.groovy**

```
root = "/home/baseConf"

test {
    dir =  root + "/testDir"
}
```

**External.groovy**

```
root = "/home/externalConf"
```

Inside controller i have:

```
println "${grailsApplication.config.root}"
println "${grailsApplication.config.test.dir}"
```

What is printed:

```
/home/externalConf
/home/baseConf/testDir
```

What I want to be printed:

```
/home/externalConf
/home/externalConf/testDir
```

What should I do to change many variables that are using one base variable in Config.groovy by exchanging this one base variable in external config file (as in example above)? Is something like this even possible?

Comment: when do you join the `External.groovy` with the regular config?  the "default" would be the commented out in the config.groovy about including external configs like this. and then root would be picked up first and all would be good.  otherwise you can always fallback to to just define the relative part of the path for `test.dir` and add root at runtime (e.g. in a config service)

Comment: I'm joining External.groovy to grails.config.locations so this will be loaded after Config.groovy (it's needed to be done that way for some reasons). I don't think that adding root at runtime will be acceptable in my case. Tho thank you for idea, I can use this in other project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change your dir variable (inside test). Check the code below.

```
test {
    dir =  "${-> root}/testDir"
}
```

This change is necessary since you want *dir* to be evaluated when it is called and not when Config is loaded. This is called late-binding (lazy evaluation) (see the answer of Ian Roberts here: [Reusing Grails variables inside Config.groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428000/reusing-grails-variables-inside-config-groovy)).

It's important to note that it is related with Groovy language (not Grails).

An Eager Evaluation Strategy can be see below:

```
def x = 1
def s = "The value of x is: ${x}"
println s //The value of x is: 1

x = 2
println s //The value of x is: 1
```

For other side, a Lazy Evaluation Strategy will evaluate the expression on-demand (call-by-need):

```
def x = 1
def s = "The value of x is: ${-> x}"
println s //The value of x is: 1

x = 2
println s //The value of x is: 2
```

Comment: Thank you! ;] Now it's working. I didn't know that lazy evaluation was done by ${ -> x} and not only ${ x }. I was told that GString was always lazy evaluating. It's important that I need do use full path of root variable if it's in other closure, because it didn't work otherwise.