# Unit testing grails ConfigSlurper behavior

Tags: grails, grails-config

I'd like to write tests that would test behavior of externalized configs and assert that what gets set is what I expect. This is for the specific case where something like this is done:

Config.groovy:

a.reused.value = 'orig'
my.variable = '${a.reused.value}'

Externalized groovy file:

a.reused.value = 'new_value'

I expect that both a.reused.value and my.variable would be 'new_value'.

Now, I think I could have my unit test read in strings representing these config files (I do similar things for other unit tests to populate Holders.grailsApplication.config, for example), utilizing perhaps merge?

But what I cannot figure out is how to get the value that Grails actually gets during application run time. Instead, I get "${a.reused.value}" in my unit tests.

Is there a way to mimic this behavior of what Grails does of actually resolving this value? I did some digging around in Grails 2.4.4 source (which is what we are using) and didn't have any luck in figuring this part out. I also did try Eval.me(), but that doesn't seem to be quite right either.

Answer (score 0):

While setting `my.variable`, you are not using a `GString` object, causing the expression to be treated as a value itself. Use double quotes to resolve expression automatically.

```
a.reused.value = 'orig' my.variable = "${a.reused.value}"
```

**Update 1:**

What you want to do is directly not possible. You are assigning the value to a variable from an expression. During evaluation of the config object for the first time, `my.variable` has been assigned a value, and now it doesn't contain an expression any more. So you have two options: 1) either reassign the second variable in external config also or 2) use a closure to assign the value to second variable.

```
my.variable = { -> "$a.reused.value" }
```

and while accessing do: `grailsApplication.config.my.variable.call()`
But again, in your code, you would have to be sure that this variable contains a closure not a value itself.

Comment: I'm actually trying to find a way to test the solution (towards the end) here: [Stackoverflow: reusing vars](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23428000/reusing-grails-variables-inside-config-groovy). Basically, what I'm trying to ensure is that I can override a re-used variable in an externalized config, and be sure that value is reflected in other variables that rely on that variable. BTW: it doesn't have to be a unit test, but I'd prefer it over integration test, since that's slower to run.

Comment: Sandeep, this does actually work with the single ticks. I can "test" this with spot testing, of course, but want to test this sort of thing more widely, if I can, with unit/integration tests.

Comment: I can see the drawbacks for using the single ticks, however. With ticks, values that should be of type ArrayList, for instance, will be of type string, instead, and same for something that should be of type Integer. It seems like I should take your approach and maybe combine it with some class that wraps ConfigObject, and uses call() if the value returned is an instance of a closure?